# Having problem in rendering forms for each instance

Tags: django, django-forms

I am creating a quiz website. Within the website there are multiple quiz topics, where each topic has a set of questions and each question has a set of answers as option. When i select a quiz topic  I want it to show the questions and options.

I tried doing the following. I created the following models

```
difficulty_choices=(('easy','easy'),('hard','hard'),('medium','medium'))
class Quiz(models.Model):
    name=models.CharField(max_length=200)
    topic=models.CharField(max_length=100)
    number_of_questions=models.IntegerField()
    difficulty=models.CharField(max_length=100,choices=difficulty_choices)
    TimeLimit=models.IntegerField(blank=True)
    def get_questions(self):
        return self.questions_set.all()[:self.number_of_questions]


class Questions(models.Model):
    text=models.CharField(max_length=200)
    quiz=models.ForeignKey(Quiz,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    correct=models.CharField(max_length=25)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.text)
    def get_answers(self):
        return self.answers_set.all()
class Answers(models.Model):
    text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    question = models.ForeignKey(Questions, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    def __str__(self):
        return f"Question: {self.question.text}, Answer: {self.text}"
class UserAnswer(models.Model):
    quiz=models.ForeignKey(Quiz,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    question = models.ForeignKey(Questions, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    answer = models.ForeignKey(Answers, on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True,blank=True)
```

and forms.py is

```
class QuizForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Quiz
        fields = ['text']
        exclude = ["text"]  # Add other fields as needed
        
    selected_answer = forms.ChoiceField(
        label="",
        choices=[],  # We'll update choices dynamically
        widget=forms.RadioSelect
    )
    
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(QuizForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        
        quiz_instance = kwargs.get('instance')
        questions = quiz_instance.get_questions()
        answer_choices = []
        for question in questions:
            answers = question.get_answers()
            answer_choices=[(answer.id, answer.text) for answer in answers]
            
            self.fields["selected_answer"] = forms.ChoiceField(
                    label='select the correct option',
                    choices=answer_choices,
                    widget=forms.RadioSelect
                )
```

Here in forms I have used the for loop to iterate through each question in a quiz instance.
To save the selected answer, I have created the following views.py

```
@login_required
def quizquestions(request, pk):
    try:
        quiz_instance = Quiz.objects.get(pk=pk)
        
    except Quiz.DoesNotExist:
        # Handle the case when the question doesn't exist
        return redirect('quiz_not_found')  # Redirect to an appropriate view
     
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = QuizForm(request.POST, instance=quiz_instance)
        if form.is_valid():
            
            #selected_answer = form.cleaned_data[selected_answer]
            selected_answer_id=request.POST.get("selected_answer")
            
            selected_answer=Answers.objects.get(id=selected_answer_id)
            question_answered=selected_answer.question
            user_answer=form.save(commit=False)
            # Create a UserAnswer instance to track the selected answer
            user_answer,created = UserAnswer.objects.get_or_create(
            user=request.user,
            question=question_answered
            )
            #user_answer = UserAnswer.objects.create(user=request.user,          question=question_instance, answer=selected_answer)
            user_answer.quiz=quiz_instance
            user_answer.answer = selected_answer
            user_answer.save()
            
    else:
        form = QuizForm(instance=quiz_instance)
    context={'form':form,'quiz':quiz_instance}
    
    return render(request, 'users/quiz.html', context)
```

The template `users/quiz.html` that I have rendered is shown below,

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Quiz</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h3>Quiz</h3>
        {% for question in quiz.get_questions%}
            <b>{{question.text}}</b>
    
            <form method="post" novalidate>
        
                {% csrf_token %}
                {{form.as_p}}
                <button type="submit">save</button>
            </form>
        {% endfor %}
    </body>
</html>
```

So The problem that I am facing is, for every question, It is showing only the options belonging to the last question only. But if you see my forms.py, For every question instance i am doing

```
answers = question.get_answers()
answer_choices=[(answer.id, answer.text) for answer in answers]
```

This means that i am updating the answer choices for each question instance. But why are the choices the same for all, and that too its showing the choices of only the last question, to all questions.

Comment: The short answer is that you are not updating the answer choices for each answer instance.  Your form's init() function is overwriting the variable `answer` so by the time the template is served, `answer` only holds the values for the last iteration.  There's no way to identify which `answer` is being referred to, or which question it belongs to

Also, even though you have a QuizForm with Quiz as a model, you are, in fact, repeating your form as a form for a single Question, rather than the entire quiz, which is confusing things.